# Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Component is not ready

Tags: qt, dynamic, qml, components, qt-quick

I want create a QML item from a string of QML using the Qt.createQmlObject() function as in [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) but first time get the error: "Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Component is not ready", in second time item created correctly, what is wrong?

You can see - I was try various items: Item, Rectangle, Component (that only one has "status" property)

test application is:
main.cpp:

```
  #include <QApplication>
  #include <QWSServer>
  #include <QDeclarativeView>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    QApplication a(argc, argv, QApplication::GuiServer);

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setMinimumSize(100,100);
    view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.show();
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromUserInput("qrc:/createFromStringTest.qml"));

    return a.exec();
  }
```

createFromStringTest.qml:

```
        import QtQuick 1.1

        Rectangle {
            id: rootRectangle
            objectName: "rootRectangle"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "gray"
            border.width: 5
            border.color: "black"
            width: 50
            height: 50

            property int testCount: 0

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    testCount +=1;
                    console.log("====================== Runing test "+testCount+" ======================");
                    tests()
                }
            }

            // what is right?
            Item{
                id: parentItem
                objectName: "parentItem"
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("parentItem loaded");
                }
            }

            Component {
                id: parentComponent
                Item {
                    id: parentComponentItem
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        console.log("parentComponentItem loaded");
                    }
                }
            }

            property list<Item> parentListItem
            property list<Component> parentListComponent

            Rectangle {
                id: parentRectangle
                objectName: "parentRectangle"
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("parentRectangle loaded");
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("rootRectangle loaded ");
            }

            Component.onDestruction: {
                console.log("rootRectangle destroyed ");
            }

            function tests(){
                try{
                    var newObjectparentItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.1; Rectangle {objectName: "dynparentItem";anchors.centerIn: parent; anchors.fill: parent; border.width: 10; border.color: "red";}',parentItem,"parentItem:");
                    console.log("parentItem OK ");
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("parentItem error: "+e);
                }

                try{
                    var newObjectparentComponent = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.1; Rectangle {objectName: "dynparentComponent";anchors.centerIn: parent; anchors.fill: parent; border.width: 10; border.color: "red";}',parentComponent,"parentComponent:");
                    console.log("parentComponent OK ");
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("parentComponent error: "+e);
                }

                try{
                    var newObjectparentComponentItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.1; Rectangle {objectName: "dynparentComponentItem";anchors.centerIn: parent; anchors.fill: parent; border.width: 10; border.color: "red";}',parentComponentItem,"parentComponentItem:");
                    console.log("parentComponentItem OK ");
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("parentComponentItem error: "+e);
                }

                try{
                    var newObjectparentListItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.1; Rectangle {objectName: "dynparentListItem";anchors.centerIn: parent; anchors.fill: parent; border.width: 10; border.color: "red";}',parentListItem,"parentListItem:");
                    console.log("parentListItem OK ");
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("parentListItem error: "+e);
                }

                try{
                    var newObjectparentListComponent = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.1; Rectangle {objectName: "dynparentListComponent";anchors.centerIn: parent; anchors.fill: parent; border.width: 10; border.color: "red";}',parentListComponent,"parentListComponent:");
                    console.log("parentListComponent OK ");
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("parentListComponent error: "+e);
                }

                try{
                    var newObjectparentRectangle = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.1; Rectangle {objectName: "dynparentRectangle";anchors.centerIn: parent; anchors.fill: parent; border.width: 10; border.color: "red";}',parentRectangle,"parentRectangle:");
                    console.log("parentRectangle OK ");
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("parentRectangle error: "+e);
                }
            }
        }
```

output:

```
Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!
rootRectangle loaded 
parentRectangle loaded
parentItem loaded
====================== Runing test 1 ======================
parentItem error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Component is not ready
parentComponent error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Component is not ready
parentComponentItem error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: parentComponentItem
parentListItem error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Missing parent object
parentListComponent error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Missing parent object
parentRectangle error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Component is not ready
====================== Runing test 2 ======================
parentItem OK 
parentComponent OK 
parentComponentItem error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: parentComponentItem
parentListItem error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Missing parent object
parentListComponent error: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Missing parent object
parentRectangle OK 
rootRectangle destroyed
```

Used Qt 4.8

Comment: Check the error message.

Comment: @ddriver  it in the subject, but what is mean and how to avoid error if parentComponent.status always === 1 (Ready) ? Why in second time noting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in third argument of function Qt.createQmlObject(QML string, parent ID, filename) the filename in my example consist the ":" symbol - without it work as expected!

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, I got the "Component is not ready" error when dynamically creating an object with Qt.createComponent + Component.createObject and there is a QML error in the component.

One way to spot the error is to statically add an instance of that component to your QML app, so that the error with line number will be printed when running the app.

Answer (score 0):

For the case like yours use [Qt.createComponent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method) to dynamically initialize the component you use. With component initialized you can call then [Component.CreateObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method). Or you could have used one parentComponent for that: `parentComponent.CreateObject(QmlItem, "QML properties")`. I usually use [Qt.createQmlObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) for doing dynamic things with QML window immediately in this QML file and don't create any new QML context for it.

Mind that in most cases you don't even need to use neither of the above but manipulate some [QML Repeater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#details) and the data model for it. That way you can provide smart delegate to customize dynamically created items. But this topic is much more than the answer to your question.

Comment: I need create item from string received from network.